# How to get the IP of a MySql Server for other devices to use

Tags: mysql

I have a Java project that connects to a database to get/store information. This works fine, but if I distribute this to another computer, it wouldn't work because the database is on `localhost`. I have researched this and it is said that you must replace `localhost` with the IP of your MySQL server. The only problem is the ways to do this only returns `localhost` instead of the numbers. I have tried `SELECT host FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id();` and several others that only return `localhost`. I need to find the numbers so other devices can connect to this database and get/store information. Also, just putting my IP address didn't work.

I'm on a mac.

Comment: On a Windows machine `ipconfig` will tell you the address, for Linux generally `ifconfig` will do the job. That might not help if your machine gets an address by DHCP since the address can change. You need to fix the address and add it to DNS or WINS or whatever name resolution system your organisation uses.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention I'm on a mac

Comment: On Mac you can also use ifconfig

Comment: I used this but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. A lot of stuff appeared on my screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end you need to go to your internet routers settings, find out the IP address the router is facing to the internet (external IP), find out which internal IP your computer has (On standard this might be something like 192.168.2.xxx), configure the router to allow access from outside and route Port 80 to the IP of your computer.

But I do not recommend to do that. You should not open your computer to the internet.

I suggest you search for a free mySQL database provider in the internet, move your database and use this.

Comment: Okay, I will look at those. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can ask MySQL to give you the hostname. It might not be the FQDN, but this should get you far enough that you can look it up via normal networking tools.

```
mysql> SELECT @@hostname;
+---------------+
| @@hostname    |
+---------------+
| DUT1-C7920343 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This comes up with my computer then a `.local` after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this "java project" on your own computer, and the MySQL database is connecting to local host, then your MySQL database is on your computer.   If you're wanting other devices within your network to connect to this MySQL database, you just need your machines IP address on your local network.  (Keep in mind, if it's setup DHCP, that number can change periodically).   If you're wanting people from outside your internet connection (i.e. from somewhere else) then you need to look into port forwarding and a bunch of other fun stuff.

Comment: Hello, I have already tried this, but I couldn't even make the connection from my own computer.